# What are the major beer competitions and how do you enter?

Tags: brewing, taste

In the advertising, you see certain beers saying that they have been awarded gold medals at various competitions, or other accolades earned.

Is there a list of what are considered to be the major beer competitions, and how would you go about entering? Is that even possible for a craft brewer, or would you need to be a major manufacturer?

Comment: I think this question is too broad as written, but if you focus it on major competitions you'd encounter as a consumer (not as a prospective entrant), that would be a valuable question.  Maybe you could ask about entering craft-brewing competitions separately.  (Be sure to explain what you seek to get out of the experience; don't just ask for a list.)

Comment: What if you don't know what the major beer competitions are? Personally, I could probably name one if pressed. Maybe. I didn't know that there were separate competitions for craft brewing.